# How to start computer with IE open and can't do anything else

Tags: internet-explorer, uac, kiosk

I have a computer with two users on it: one Administrator and one User. I want to computer to automatically log into the User Account and open Internet Explorer. The User should not be able to do anything else, just browsing.

I could do this easily by disabling all programs with Parental Controls and opening IE in Kiosk Mode. The problem is that I need the address bar and there is no Address Bar in kiosk mode.

So is there a way I can enable the address bar in kiosk mode? If not, is there a way I could simulate kiosk mode by opening IE in fullscreen with everything shut off except the Address Bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Set IE to full screen mode (F11)

2) Set `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE` to the Shell. I don't remember the exact registry key

3) Disable access to everything you can in GPEDIT.MSC

4) Get software to block out the right-click and special key combinations (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> for example)

Comment: Using this method, as the administrator, how do I bypass this to do work on the computer?

Comment: Log in as the administrator. Most of these restrictions can be applied to limited users instead of all users

Comment: What about step 2? Changing the shell will affect all users right? And without windows explorer I won't be able to do any administrative work

Comment: You can open Task Manager as an Admin, then select File->New Process and type `explorer.exe`